# how to sum up data based on last month and year for a particular group in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a below dataframe that contains monthly data by id:

```
id dt           tbl_cnt char_cnt 
01 2016-01-01   2       3
01 2016-02-01   NaN     1
01 2016-03-01   12      2
01 2016-04-01   2       3
01 2016-05-01   1       1
01 2016-06-01   2       3
..
02 2016-02-01   2       NaN
02 2016-03-01   1       1
02 2016-04-01   2       3
02 2016-05-01   2       3
02 2016-06-01   2       3
02 2016-07-01   2       3
```

And want to write a function which take date and custom month number ; e.g a feature can look like calculate sum from the last 2 months, 3 months etc. and want the below output

```
id month tbl_cnt_last_2m tbl_cnt_last_3m  char_cnt_last_2m char_cnt_last_3m 
01 01    NaN             NaN              NaN               NaN
01 02    NaN             NaN              NaN               NaN
01 03    2               NaN              4                 NaN
01 04    12              14               3                 6
..
02 01    NaN             NaN              NaN               NaN
02 02    NaN             NaN              NaN               NaN
02 03    NaN             NaN              NaN               NaN
02 04    3               NaN              1                 NaN
..
```

Please could you advise

I have used below code but that picks value from previous group as well which is incorrect:-

```
df['tbl_cnt_last_2m'] = df.groupby("id")['tbl_cnt'].shift(1).rolling(2,min_periods=1).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Grouper for the same.

```
g = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"))
g.sum()
```

df1 being your dataframe